# How to split Ruby string by "\r\n"?

Tags: ruby, string, split

Given a string like:

```
s = "G o o d\r\nDay\r\n\r\n\r\nStack\r\n\r\nOverflow\r\n"
```

I would like to:

- Split it by `(\r\n)+`, i.e. I would like to get: `["G o o d", "Day", "Stack", "Overflow"]`

  I tried `s.split(/(\r\n)+/)` but it doesn't give me the expected result.

  Why ? How could I get the expected result ?
- Get the number of `\r\n` in array, i.e. the expected result is: [1, 3, 2]

  How would you do this ?

I use Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost, try this:

```
s.split /[\r\n]+/
s.scan(/[\r\n]+/).map { |e| e.size/2 }
```

This gives `[1,3,2,1]` which is possibly the "real" answer. But otherwise, `s.chomp.scan...` would give `[1,3,2]`.

Comment: This also splits on lone `\r`, `\n`, `\n\n\r\n` etc.  That's not exactly what was asked, but probably a better idea.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
s = "G o o d\r\nDay\r\n\r\n\r\nStack\r\n\r\nOverflow\r\n"

s.split(/[\r\n]+/) # => ["G o o d", "Day", "Stack", "Overflow"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to split by `/[\r\n]+/`

```
"G o o d\r\nDay\r\n\r\n\r\nStack\r\n\r\nOverflow\r\n".split(/[\r\n]+/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `split(/(\r\n)+/)` doesn't work as you expect because [capture groups are included](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165) in the returned array:

> If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.

An easy solution would be to split on `\r\n` and the throw away the empties:

```
s.split(/\r\n/).reject { |s| s == '' }
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be getting `\r\n` in your strings, unless you're reading in a Windows text file in binary mode. Read it in in text mode, and Ruby will fix the `\r`s for you automatically.